# .click() not working with specific selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Setting the Selector's:

```
            btNext = $('<a>' + options.labelNext + '</a>').attr("href", "#").addClass("buttonNext");
            btPrevious = $('<a>' + options.labelPrevious + '</a>').attr("href", "#").addClass("buttonPrevious");
            btFinish = $('<a>' + options.labelFinish + '</a>').attr("href", "#").addClass("buttonFinish");
            test = $('<a class="LinkMe" href="#">MotherBoard</a>')
```

Click():

```
                $(test).click(function () {
                    showStep(0);
                });
                $(btNext).click(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('buttonDisabled')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    doForwardProgress();
                    if ($.isFunction(options.onNext)) {
                        if (!options.onNext.call(this, $(steps))) {
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                $(btPrevious).click(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('buttonDisabled')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    doBackwardProgress();
                    if ($.isFunction(options.onPrevious)) {
                        if (!options.onPrevious.call(this, $(steps))) {
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                $(btFinish).click(function () {
                    if (!$(this).hasClass('buttonDisabled')) {
                        if ($.isFunction(options.onFinish)) {
                            if (!options.onFinish.call(this, $(steps))) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            var frm = obj.parents('form');
                            if (frm && frm.length) {
                                frm.submit();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                });
```

ALL of the click functions work EXCEPT the selector (test), ive tried taking the click function out of the plugin and in a

`$(document).ready(function () {});`

and it still doesnt work thier, Please help.

Comment: Those aren't selectors. A selector is CSS syntax describing the elements on the page you're targeting, like `"#foo > .bar"`. What you're doing is creating elements by passing HTML markup to jQuery.

Comment: are you adding these dynamic elements to dom

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cvQ23/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing:

```
test.click(function() {});
```

or

```
$("a.LinkMe").click(function() {});
// since test is a link having a class 'LinkMe'
```

But if those elements are dynamically added into your HTML, you can use `.on()` or `.delegate()`

```
$("a.LinkMe").on("click", function() {});
// OR
$(document).on("click", "a.LinkMe", function() {});
// OR
$("body").delegate("a.LinkMe", "click", function() {});
```

Comment: I see. How about these: `$("a.LinkMe").on("click", function() {})` or `$(document).on("click", "a.LinkMe", function() {})`

Comment: $(document).on("click", "a.LinkMe", function() {}) this worked ty

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Instead of doing

```
test = $('<a class="LinkMe" href="#">MotherBoard</a>')
```

You'll want to do instead

```
$test = $('a.LinkMe');
// or just
$test = $('.LinkMe');
```

Same for the `btNext`, `btPrevious`, `btFinish`. I'm not sure why they work, maybe someone else can explain it to me.

Comment: None :( ive tried multiple ideas, all those included here and others,  The only way i can make it work is if i apply onclick="" into the HTML

Comment: @DirtyRedz It seems like you've inserted the element to the document after the document is loaded. In that case you have to bind the event to the document or others. Also, showing us your `showStep` function will be helpful.